# Worksheet loaded from datatable then formatting column as date results in exception?

Tags: epplus

Im bringing in several datatables, each into seperate worksheets.  Several sheets have date values, some in the underlying datatable as varchar, which renders as expected.  The others that are underlying datetime, display in the worksheet as a number.  How can I tell the columns in those sheets to be formatted as datetime

```
            ExcelWorksheet wksht1 = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WeeklySummary");
            wksht1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dsResults.Tables["first"], true);
            wksht1.Column(0).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
            wksht1.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

When I try I get an exception

> {"Column number out of bounds"}

What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

The `ExcelColumn` class is actually 1-based, not 0-based, like many things in Epplus:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L1719

```
public ExcelColumn Column(int col)
{
    CheckSheetType();
    if (col < 1 || col > ExcelPackage.MaxColumns)
    {
        throw (new ArgumentException("Column number out of bounds"));
    }

    ...
}
```

So changing to:

```
wksht1.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
wksht1.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```